# infinitive-to : what is the difference between two type of infinitives

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, grammaticality

I wonder about the usage of word “to” in the following sentences:
In the first example, the first phrase before ‘to say’ is a full sentence and in the second example it follows an adjective. I can understand the second one but
I was mistakenly writing "that's really hurts to saying..." but I don't know why we can’t use preposition here instead of infinitive form.
Also I think that hurt is a intransitive verb so that it cant take infinitive verb as an object. So in my opinion the first sentence must be wrong in this perspective.

> 1. *It really hurts to say that is correct*.
> 2. *It is hard to say goodbye.*

Comment: 1. is ungrammatical: the genitive _that's_ (meaning _that is_) makes no sense at all. You need the extraposition construction like the one in 2 _It really hurts to say that is correct_.

Comment: @BillJ You’re right. I need to change the first sentence. But I still wonder what is the difference of these two ‘to’ in functioning.can you explain the difference ? Also i think hurts is intransitive verb so it can not be used with infinitives Am I correct?

Comment: They both have the same construction in which "to" is a subordinator functioning as a marker of subordination: The _to_ infinitival clauses are called extraposed subjects. Yes: "hurt" is intransitive here.

Comment: You could rephrase the first one as "It is really painful to say that is correct", which gives it the same structure as the second.

Comment: The basic (non-extraposed) versions would be _To say that it is correct really hurts_, / _To say goodbye is hard_ , where the infinitival clauses are subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *It really hurts* [*to say that is correct*].
>
> [2] *It is hard* [*to say goodbye*].

These are both extraposition constructions where the bracketed infinitival clauses are in extraposed position, outside the verb phrase.

The bracketed expressions are both *to*-infinitivals where "to" is a subordinator functioning as a marker for the infinitival verb phrases.

The basic (non-extraposed) versions would be

> [3] [*To say that it is correct*] *really hurts*.
>
> [4] [*To say goodbye*] *is hard*.

where this time the bracketed infinitival clauses are subjects.

Comment: It was a very good explanation. Now it is very clear to me. You end my brain suffering thank you :) 
Also, I tried to write a sentence by using 'that' this time to extrapose. Is the following sentence grammatically correct?
 
"It really hurts that you say goodbye."

Comment: @cerenaksengur  Yes, it is OK.